# SSL and IP addresses on a dedicated server

Tags: ssl, shared-hosting, dedicated-server

I've just moved from a shared web hosting server operating on WHM/cPanel running six domains with 1 dedicated IP address.  1 of the 6 domains has an SSL certificate.

I have since moved to a dedicated server also with 1 dedicated IP and running cPanel/WHM with the same six domains.  I want 1 of the domains to have the SSL certificate but I am being told that it's not possible unless I buy another dedicated IP address.  I want to question the hosting provider on this but they haven't really acknowledged it - they've just kept saying that it needs its own IP as the IP I am currently using is shared between my six domains.

Does anyone have any experience of this and tell me why my new expensive dedicated hosting provider can't setup SSL using the certificate as I had done before on my shared server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SSL for only one domain this should be no problem.  Configure a virtual server on port 443 with the SSL certificate.  Configure virtual servers on port 80 for all the domains.  You may want the HTTP service for the SSL domain to automatically forward to HTTPS.

If you configure all the domains on both HTTP and HTTPS, you may want to redirect HTTPS connection on the non SSL domains to redirect to HTTP.  The Apache rewrite documentation should cover the rewrite rules required.

I don't know the capabilities of CPANEL but either option should work.  Comments by others indicate you may have to manually edit the Apache configuration for the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You require 1 ip address per SSL certificate/domain. Afraid that's the way it works. You can have as many non ssl domains as you want per ip.

Comment: That's what I want but they're saying I can't because the non-ssl domains will be sharing the same domain as my dedicated IP with an SSL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that, but it requires you not to use Cpanel and edit Apaches config directly, most providers only charge $1 for an extra IP. I suggest you just get another IP if you don't want to start editing configs manually.

Comment: Unfortunately the hosting provider wants $8/month and I thought it's an unnecessary cost if my previous hosting provider was able to do it and yet my dedicated provider which I pay premium support for isn't able to.

Answer (score 0):

It is how SSL works. You can only have one SSL per IP. This is because the connection needs to be encrypted before Apache can decide which site it needs to serve. You cannot have two HTTPS sites on the same IP. You can however have one HTTPS site and multiple normal ones. Problem is the other sites would be accessible using https and get a security warning in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You would need multiple IP addresses for multiple SSL certificates. But one SSL certificate can have more domains in it. Either by including multiple domains (example.org, serverfault.com, shop.example.org) or using a wildcard certificate (*.example.org).

Your shared hoster had probably put multiple domains into a single SSL certificate, hence you would be fine with 1 dedicated IP. Your dedicated provider possibly want to push you to use a dedicated SSL certificate for each domain, each requiring a dedicated IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what the actual problem is. You have six domains, one of which requires SSL. You have one dedicated IP address. This should work just fine (see BillThor's answer).

Why do you need another SSL-enabled domain? Does Cpanel require SSL? If Cpanel is the only way to configure your host, perhaps your hosting provider should pay for the extra IP and not you? If your hosting provider is requiring you to have one IP address for all your HTTP domains and one IP address for your HTTPS domain, I suggest you contact them and find out why. It is unnecessary, although I can't think of anything "wrong" it, other than you have to pay for another dedicated IP address.

Comment: The problem is the hosting provider won't do for me what the shared hosting provider did without any issues.  I only want one domain with SSL.  I have one certificate for this domain and one dedicated IP address.  But they're saying because I have six domains on the same IP address (all domains belong to me and its my dedicated server) they can't install it.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken there is absolutely NO (technical) reason why they should be prevented from doing this. Who is your hosting provider? You might need to call them and figure out exactly why they don't want to/can't do this. Like others have said, there's nothing technically infeasible about your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I'm with UKFast.  I'll try to push them on the topic further.